# How connect nlatexdb with database hosted with XAMPP?

Tags: database, sql

I'm trying to connect with a database I create with XAMPP. I think it's mysql, and tried *MySql.Data.MySqlClient*, but not connect. Gives **Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed** error.

I tried with *System.Data.SqlClient*, but gives other issue: **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

I connect with db in other instances, like Power BI.

This is the tex I'm trying to compile with nlatexdb, but gives that errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\texdbconnectionnet{System.Data.SqlClient}{Server=localhost;Database=dbexercicios; Uid=user; Pwd=pass;}
\texdbdef{##tudo}{select Tipo, Area, Dificuldade from tlistaexercicios}{##Tipo, ##Area, ##Dificuldade}

    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \texdbfor{##tudo}{##Tipo & ##Area & ##Dificuldade \\}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `nlatexdb.exe -P`? That will return a list of available data providers on your system. `System.Data.SqlClient` is the data provider for Microsoft SqlServer, so that one will not work for MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Further question: which operating system do you use (Windows/Mac/Linux)? How did you install the XAMPP stack? This is relevant for finding out how you can use or install the correct database driver.

Comment: Also: there are several packages available for maintaining and using exercise/exam databases in LaTeX itself, without external tools. An example is [xsim](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/xsim_manual.pdf), that has some database-like functionality such as selecting exercises by difficulty level or by topic (for that package the exercise contents is stored either in a separate `.tex` file or as part of the main file).

Comment: @Marijn yes, I typed this command to see all data providers; I'm using Windows 10, and not install XAMPP at C: .

I saw xsim, but I want to have many ways to one question and possibility to multiple answers.

Comment: Ok, and which data providers are installed? Anything that says MySQL in the name or description? If not, then you need to install it, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-binary-nuget.html for more information.

Comment: Yeap... I installed it.

  "Name:MySQL Data Provider
Description:.Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL
InvariantName:MySql.Data.MySqlClient."  

When I call this in .tex with nlatexdb at powershell, output this error:

 "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider."

Comment: And is it also listed in your `machine.config` file (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory)?